# Is there a way to bind ng-model or a factory to an iframe in design mode

Tags: javascript, angularjs, iframe

I am trying to create a very very basic editor that allows you to bold text, add links, add unordered lists, and images and that's it. I set up my Controller but I was wondering how you would bind a factory or variable to the iframe so that when I type in it that the variable that is storing the html is updated?

here is the basic app html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="HtmlEditor">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="lib/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body ng-controller="AppCtrl as app">
    <div class="header">
        Email Creator
    </div>
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="col-md-5">
            <form action="" set-url="controller">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="">Subject</label>
                    <input type="text" name="subject" class="form-control" ng-model="app.settings.subject">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="">Title</label>     
                    <input type="text" name="title" class="form-control" ng-model="app.settings.title">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="">Signature</label>     
                    <input type="text" name="signature" class="form-control" ng-model="app.settings.signature">
                </div>
                <div class="editor">
                    <div html-editor="richText"></div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-7">
            <div preview>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

here is the part of the app.js file that is relevant to the question the rest is just scaffolding for other directives and controllers to support functionality

```
var app = angular.module("HtmlEditor", ['ngSanitize'])

.factory("Settings", function(){
    var settings  = {

    }

    settings.setUrl = function(url){

        settings.url = url+".cfc";

    }

    return settings;
})

.controller("AppCtrl", function(Settings){
    var appCtrl = this;

    appCtrl.settings = Settings;

    appCtrl.filter = function(){

    }

})

.directive("htmlEditor", function(Settings){

    return {
        restrict:"A",
        scope:{
            htmlEditor:"@"
        },
        controller:"AppCtrl",
        replace:true,
        template:'<iframe name="{{::htmlEditor}}" id="{{::htmlEditor}}"></iframe>',
        link:function(scope, element, attr, appCtrl){
            console.log(element.contents())
            element.contents()[0].designMode = "On";
            /*var iframeDocument = element[0].contentDocument || element[0].contentWindow.document;
            iframeDocument.designMode = "On";*/
            appCtrl.settings.editor = element.contents()[0];

            console.log(appCtrl.settings.editor);
        }
    }

})
```

Answer (score 1):

this is how I got it to work the it basically emulates the ngModel functionality. I just posted the answer just in case anyone else was trying to do something similar and couldn't figure it out.

```
return {
        restrict:"A",
        scope:{
            htmlEditor:"@"
        },
        require:"ngModel",
        replace:true,
        template:'<iframe name="{{::htmlEditor}}" id="{{::htmlEditor}}"></iframe>',
        link:function(scope, element, attr, ngModel){
            console.log(element.contents())
            var editor = element.contents()[0];
            editor.designMode = "On";
            Settings.editor = editor;

            console.log(ngModel);
            Settings.body = element.contents().children().find('body');

            element.contents()
            .bind("blur keyup change", function() {

                scope.$apply(function(){

                    Settings.isEmpty = !Settings.body.html().length > 0;
                    console.log(Settings.isEmpty);
                    Settings.html = Settings.body.html();

                });

            });
    }

}
```

Comment: but, there are a small problem: the current window doesn't to access data on iframe. You could to try to create a callback, or use an event to send from iframe to current window the editor data. I will try to made a example on jsbin for you.

Comment: OK Thank you. I can post the more of the code.  I have not been able to figure out the ngModel part of it but It works well enough for the purposes of what I needed it to do.

Comment: If you can, could you to create a jsbin project with your code? You should to assume get directly from iframe sometimes doesn't allowed by browser security. Ex: jQuery('iframe').getElementById('myTextarea').value (or similar code) will returns empty. But javascript callbacks could be used always between page and iframe.

Comment: and more, I think you need two points: update the iframe textArea or similar component when model changes, and update the model variable when text is changed. Is it correct?

Comment: I actually got it working with out that, I put it without using the textarea, texareas don't take html the only way to it is using the "contenteditable" attribute.  the document.execCommand() function creates the html and the scope.$apply updates the variable that is being evaluated by ngSanitize. There is no jquery on in the code I am using pure angular(jqlite)

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason that you have the iframe in the directive?

What i have done in the past is set url in a scope variable.

```
<iframe name="pdfIframe" ng-src="{{currentLeadSheetUrl}}" id="pdfIframe" width="80%" height="500px" ></iframe>
```

Comment: Actually yes I am making a very basic re-usable editor.  I found a solution that works but I am still trying to figure out the kinks.  But you can emulate the functionality of ng-model by using inside of the directive bind("keyup, blur, change") that gives you the live-updating when you combine that with scope.$apply.  But the source part of it is not what I need to work.  I need to output the content inside the iframe using ngSanitize.