# Iframe not showing content inside an MVC View called inside AngularJS directive

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, iframe

I need to show a physical folder content inside an iframe. This iframe is located inside and MVC View which is called in the RenderBody() action of a Layout which is marked with an AngularJS directive. My page is showing the iframe and it src attribute is set but it isn't show anything. My goal is as simple as show the folder content as in the browser. I attached in here my MVC Controller and View code and also the section in the Layout with the RenderBody. Thanks in advance.

View

```
@using System.Configuration
@using System.Web.Optimization
@using ReportViewerForMvc;
@model HtmlString
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Reports";
    Layout = "~/Areas/Authorization/Views/Shared/Layout.cshtml";
    ViewData["Module"] = "sbo-auth";
}

@section PageTitle
{
    <h5 class="page-title">Reports</h5>
}

<div id="root">
    @if (Model != null)
    {
        <iframe id="iframe" src="@Model"></iframe>
    }
    else
    {
        <h3>The path to reports server is incorrect.</h3>
    }
</div> 

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/Authorization")
```

Controller

```
    [Authorize]
    [Route("reports-repository")]
    public ActionResult ReportsFileExplorer()
    {
        var path = (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EodReportsPath"])
                    && System.IO.Directory.Exists(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EodReportsPath"]))
            ? new HtmlString(new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EodReportsPath"]).AbsoluteUri)
            : null;
        return View("ReportsFileExplorer", path);
    }
```

Layout portion

```
<div class="page-container row-fluid">
    <!-- BEGIN SIDEBAR -->
    <div class="page-sidebar nav-collapse collapse">
        @Html.MvcSiteMap().Menu(false)
    </div>
    <!-- END SIDEBAR -->
    <!-- BEGIN PAGE -->
    <div class="page-content">
        <!-- BEGIN PAGE CONTAINER-->
        <div class="container-fluid" ng-cloak>
            @RenderBody()
        </div>
        <!-- END PAGE CONTAINER-->
    </div>
    <!-- END PAGE -->
</div>
```

Comment: you sure that `src` is a full web url with protocol, domain etc ?

Comment: Yes. In the developer tool of the browser, i see the i frame properly created with it src attribute set to "file:///C:TempReports/" which is the folder which content the iframe has to show.

Comment: iframe needs to be served from http, not `file://`. Use a proper web path

Comment: I also tested it putting websites urls with http protocol where @Model is and it doesn't show anything either.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to bind ng-model or a factory to an iframe in design mode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29237904/is-there-a-way-to-bind-ng-model-or-a-factory-to-an-iframe-in-design-mode)